# Import a JavaScript function without importing additional dependencies in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies

If there's a zero-dependencies function `zdfun`, but in a module/file `foo.js` that imports further dependencies, and I'm solely interested in `zdfun`, is it possible to import it without Node trying to load all the other dependencies in `foo.js`?

Obviously one should normally just pull `zdfun` out, place it in its own module, and import that in `foo.js`. Sadly this is not feasible in this case for various reasons.

Comment: do you mean `import it` or `install it`?

Answer (score 0):

if `zdfun` is declared in its own file where no other depencies are imported you can do :

```
import { zdfun } from '<module_name>';
```

And this will not import useless depencies.

I hope this answer your question

Comment: Of course, but I said "load" not "import". The NodeJS loader still tries to resolve all the dependencies, e. g. if they aren't there you get an exception, even if in the actual code they aren't needed.